# How can I get the info from the API? Swift 4

Tags: swift

I try to get individual information from this API:

https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=DNR,DIFF,ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=CLIMATOLOGY&outputList=ASCII&lat=40.39&lon=-3.74&user=anonymous"

So far I am able to print in the console the API result. I'd like to extract from it the latitude, longitude (even though I can obtain these 2 from the CoreLocation library, I still want to get them from the API) and the content inside the properties->parameter part (ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN, DIFF and DNR). And extract this info is where I am stuck.

I've tried to get the individual elements of the API but I can only get the full API content and not the individual ones (which later I want to put in arrays). I tried using this notation:

```
if let features = ((NASAjsonResult["features"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["geometry"] as? String {
     print("This is features: \(features)"                              
} else {
     print("ERROR for getting 'features'")
}
```

But I always get the "Error" message.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

//MARK: - Variables and constants
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var latit = 0.0
var longit = 0.0
var latitString = ""
var longitString = ""
var locationArray:[String] = []

//MARK: - Labels, tables, maps, etc. on tableView
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    return cell

}

//MARK: - ViewDidLoad()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // For use when the app is open & in the background
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    //For use when the app is open
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    //Once we have the permission of using the location:
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

//MARK: - Detect location
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    if let location = locations.first{

        latit = location.coordinate.latitude
        longit = location.coordinate.longitude
        print("Latitude: \(String(format: "%.4f", latit)), Longitude: \(String(format: "%.4f", longit))")
        latitString = String(format: "%.4f", latit)
        longitString = String(format: "%.4f", longit)
        print("Lat Str: \(latitString) | Lon Str: \(longitString)")

        //Adding elements to array.
        self.locationArray.append(latitString)//String(format: "%.4f", latit))
        self.locationArray.append(longitString)//String(format: "%.4f", longit))

        print(locationArray)

        //MARK: - Using NASA API to get DNI, GHI and DHI
        if let NASAurl = URL(string: "https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=DNR,DIFF,ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=CLIMATOLOGY&outputList=ASCII&lat=\(latitString)&lon=\(longitString)&user=anonymous"){

            print("This is NASA's url: \(NASAurl)")

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NASAurl) { (data, response, error) in

                if error != nil{

                    print(error!)

                }else{

                    if let urlContent = data{

                        do{

                            let NASAjsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
                            print("This is NASA jsonResult: \(NASAjsonResult)")

                            if let features = ((NASAjsonResult["features"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["geometry"] as? String {

                                print("This is features: \(features)")

                            }else {print("ERROR for features")}



                        }catch{

                            print("NASA JSON Processing Failed.")

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            task.resume()

        }

    }

}

}
```

This project is far from being finished and I know it still has a lot of bugs, but for now I only want to focus on getting the information from the API.

Thanks in advance again!

Comment: What is NASAurl and NASAjsonResult?

Comment: You should have a look at the [`JSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) and [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) APIs

Comment: I'm not sure why you use NSArray. But try to convert it into [[String: Any]] instead

Comment: That's so bad, but `((NASAjsonResult["features"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["geometry"] as? String` is wrong, `((NASAjsonResult["features"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["geometry"]` is a Dictionary, not a String, that's why it fails. If you don't do the `as ? String`, you should get a result, meaning that's it's the String cast that is failing, and that's normal because it's not castable into a String.

Comment: Thank you all. I will review all of your comments and learn more about the JSONSerialization and Codable APIs as Lukas suggested.

Comment: “but I can only get the full API content and not the individual ones” Makes no sense. Once you’ve parse the whole thing, you have the individual parts and can do what you like with them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way (not the prettiest one) to extract the info you want from the response given by that API:

```
guard let NASAjsonResult = NASAjsonResult as? [String : Any] else {
    print("NASAjsonResult is not a Dictionary")
    return
}

guard let features = NASAjsonResult["features"] as? Array<[String : Any]> else {
    print("features is not an Array")
    return
}

guard let singleFeature = features.first else {
    print("There are no features")
    return
}

if let geometry = singleFeature["geometry"] as? [String : Any],
    let coordinates = geometry["coordinates"] as? Array<Double> {

    let latitude = coordinates[0]
    let longitude = coordinates[1]

    print(latitude)
    print(longitude)
}

if let properties = singleFeature["properties"] as? [String : Any],
    let parameter = properties["parameter"] as? [String : Any] {

    let ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN = parameter["ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN"] as? [String : Double]
    let DIFF = parameter["DIFF"] as? [String : Double]
    let DNR = parameter["DNR"] as? [String : Double]

    print(ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN)
    print(DIFF)
    print(DNR)
}
```

If you want, you can define "latitude", "longitude", "ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN", "DIFF" and "DNR" outside the IF's block to use theme somewhere else, I just put them there to print them.

Comment: This is useful, thank you. I will analyze it and "play" with the code to get what I need. I appreciate your time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how to get the latitude and longitude using Swift 4 Decodable structs.

Assume `d` is your JSON data returned from the API. Then:

```
struct Outer : Decodable {
    let features: [Feature]
}
struct Feature : Decodable {
    let geometry: Geometry
}
struct Geometry : Decodable {
    let coordinates: [Double]
}
let outer = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Outer.self, from: d)
let lat = outer.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0] // -3.73999
let long = outer.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1] // 40.39001
```

Obtaining ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN, DIFF and DNR is completely parallel so I won't bother to write it all out for you here. You need to do *some* of the work after all.

Comment: Thanks matt, in fact I am doing the work. It is just that I got stuck and I asked for some help after trying different (unsuscessful) methods to get the info. That's why I shared the code with the community to show you what I have done (wrong) and get some feedback from more experienced programmers as you. I appreciate the time you took to answer my inquiry and show me a way to solve the problem. Kind regards.